# Javascript - Wildcard inside an IF statement

Tags: javascript, wildcard

I have a javascript if statement which checks whether the URL of the current page matches a string. The string being represented here by item.page.

I want to use wildcards as per below but it isn't working. How should I format this expression?

```
 if ('*' + item.page + '*' != '*' + document.location.href + '*' {
```

Comment: Discover [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.  (Jamie Zawinski, 1997)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf(item.page) > -1) {
 console.log("Current URL contains" + item.page);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ubxrhuob/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't abuse [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Use [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
if (document.location.href.includes(item.page)) {
    // …
}
```

Comment: What about browser compatibility?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Supports browsers from before I was born. Use [babel](https://babeljs.io).

Comment: why is using `indexOf` an abuse here? `indexOf` returns a number stating the position of substring whereas includes returns a `boolean` based on the substring's existence.  I believe it is better to use `indexOf` until every environment supports ES6.

Comment: It's an abuse since we're not interested in the index in the slightest. We just want to know if a string includes another. That's what `String.prototype.includes` is for. (The "Say what you mean" approach leads to actually readable code.)

Comment: As for "until every environment supports ES6": That's a lame excuse; IE6 will never support ES6. Just get used to the fact that we'll have to transpile our high-level languages down to lower-level languages to support the whole web. It's been like that since FORTRAN, when developers refused to stop writing assembly.

Comment: @Chiru Internet Explorer supports it does it? I'm seeing a very different story

Comment: @SmokeyPHP You *did* check out the compiler that I've linked you to, right?

Comment: @Chiru You *do* realise that people don't convert all of their code and that ultimately you'll be running `indexOf()`, right? Just accept that a lot of people can't use this function without implementing a polyfill of some sort for unsupported browsers, jesus!

Comment: @SmokeyPHP You *do* realize that your project will quickly become unreadable/unmaintainable if you try to boil down everything to ES5, which, too, hasn't full coverage in every environment. Polyfilling has been around forever, and the web has long settled with pre-processing code (Less, SASS, TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Traceur, Babel, Jade, …). Let's give the OP some up-to-date help, and not some advice he could have used back in 1999.

Comment: @Chiru My code is fine, maybe you have problems for other reasons... just be sensible, seriously

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Is that so? Maybe you should try running `async`-, `function*`- or `Promise`-ridden code in IE7, then. (If you don't have anything more meaningful to add to this conversation, I'd like to ask you to stop adding more comments on this post now.)

Comment: @Chiru I'll just add one thing, then you can go back to using diggers to weed your garden.. I decide my supported target audience, as I write software so this sort of thing isn't an issue for me, the point is that you are providing an answer for a huge community that find this on the internet, and they should be made aware of compatibility problems. I never said your answer was wrong, but people should be made aware when a major browser doesn't support your code. Your answer shouldn't rely on tools if it isn't necessary. End of.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Sure, I guess we could agree on that. Nevertheless, what I'm saying is that today, with a new EcmaScript standard rolling in every year, it will very soon become a huge pain to ship JavaScript to certain environments if some language constructs just aren't available, so transpiling your code is pretty much the default nowadays (and not only for JS). But apart from that, `String.prototype.includes` is currently supported by the newest iteration of every major browser anyway, making this answer pretty compatible for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit conversion to regexp with no wildcards:

```
if (document.location.href.match(item.page)) ...
```